# C++ Strings/ Files

Tags: c++, string, file

I am trying to read a file which contains a list of SSNs, usernames, and passwords. I am trying to replace all but the last 4 of the socials with x's and I have a system that gives points based on the strength of the password ("accumulator" is used for this part). I am having trouble outputting the table with cout from main and was hoping to get some help. When I try to output it from main it just does the last line of the file and the SSN on that line is not x's like I wanted.  Thanks

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

void openFile(ifstream&, string, string, string);
string xReplace(ifstream& myIn, string& social, string& username, string&     password, string socialRep);
void passStrength(int& count1, int& count2, int& count3, int& accumulator,   ifstream& myIn, string& social, string& username, string& password);


int main()
{
ifstream myIn;
string path, file;
string fileName;
string social;
string username;
string password;
string socialRep = "xxx-xx";
string oneLine = social + username + password;
int count1 = 0;
int count2 = 0;
int count3 = 0;
int accumulator = 0;

openFile(myIn, path, file, fileName);
xReplace(myIn, social, username, password, socialRep);
passStrength(count1, count2, count3, accumulator, myIn, social, username, password);


myIn >> social >> username >> password >> accumulator;
while (myIn.good())

cout << "SSN\tUser Name\tPassword\tPassword Strength\n";
cout << "---------------------------------------------------------\n";
cout << social << " " << username << " " << password << " " << accumulator << "\n";


return 0;
}


void openFile(ifstream& myIn, string path, string file, string fileName)
{

path = "C:\\2430";
cout << "Enter the name of your file";
getline(cin, file);

fileName = path + "\\" + file;
cout << "The file name is " << fileName << endl;

myIn.open(fileName.c_str());
if (myIn.fail())
{
cout << "Filename was invalid\n";
exit(1);
}
cout << "The file" " " << file << "has been opened\n";

}


void passStrength(int& count1, int& count2, int& count3, int& accumulator, ifstream& myIn, string& social, string& username, string& password)
{

while (myIn >> social >> username >> password)
{
for (unsigned int i = 0; i > password.length(); i++)
if (password.length() > 8)

count1 = 1;

else count1 = 0;

int testing = -1;
testing = password.find_first_of("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ");

if (testing != password.npos)

count2 = 1;

else count2 = 0;

unsigned int testing2 = -1;
testing2 = password.find_first_of("!@#$%^&*()");
if (testing2 != password.npos)

count3 = 1;

else count3 = 0;

accumulator = count1 + count2 + count3;
//cout << social << " " << username << " " << password << " " <<accumulator<< "\n";


}
}

string xReplace(ifstream& myIn, string& social, string& username, string&    password, string socialRep)
{

myIn >> social >> username >> password;
social.replace(0, 6, socialRep);
return social;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a container to keep your records in your program. Variables can keep a single data at a time,

You can define a struct  record for following variables social, username and password  as follows:

```
struct record{
   string social;
   string username;
   string password;
};
```

And create a std::vector as follows

```
std::vector<record> my_records;
```

So when you read data from file, insert data into my_record as follows.

```
my_reccords.push_back(recod_data);
```

And process records from `my_records` and at end print data from `my_records`.